How to measure the strength of relationship
I want to use a univariate $x$ to predict univariate $y$. Both are individually approx normal time series.
When I run OLS of $y$ on lagged values of $x$, I get significant t-stat (~5) but low R2 (< 1%).
Given the low R2, I am trying to determine whether I should depend on a large $x$ to forecast a large $y$, or if most of that is just noise.
So I ran another OLS of $y$ on just $sign(x)$. Both the t-stat and R2 are slightly lower in this case.
The residuals of both regressions are pretty normal- no heteroskedasticity, or autocorrelation. Durbin watson and jarque bera both passed.
Is there any concern in the method I used? Or a better way to determine the behavior of noise vs signal here?

I cannot stress enough the importance of plots.

It is not obvious what is meant by "approx normal time series" in your question. Judging from the rest of it, it seems you meant that both your time series $x_t$ and $y_t$ follow a white noise process, where each point in time $\sim N(0,\sigma^2_x)$ for $x_t$ and $\sim N(0,\sigma^2_y)$ for $y_t$. In this case unless you have very specific domain knowledge on how those two series are related there is little to no sense trying to force some noise to predict another noise, they might simply be independent. Aside from that I have some pointers:

First of all, the title of your question is causal: you want to find the relationship between $x_t$ and $y_t$, however, then you say you want to predict $y_t$ using $x_t$. Those are two different tasks. If one variable predicts the other well, it does not in general mean that there is any causal relationship between them. Causality is about establishing how the variables are related, whereas prediction is more about model specification. I will assume you wanted causality
In order to determine if there is a relationship between the two variables, you can try to use the Granger causality test or its various modifications
In case you want to simply have one number, which quantifies the temporal dependence of your variables, you may refer to Dynamic time warping and other similar methods
Also, in general $R^2$ is a bad metric for time series data as discussed here. And linear regression is not a good method for prediction tasks in time series. It is better to use something like ARIMAX or VAR models for that if you want to stick with econometrics and not go into machine learning models

Hope that this helps

I'm not sure from the title that this question is actually about causality. That isn't to say that it shouldn't be about causality, but the reality is a lot of people only think of prediction.

Granger causality is a very limited view of causality. There a two capable modern frameworks: potential outcomes and Pearl's framework. Here is an introduction to the latter.

Yup, $R^2$ is very limited. (+1)

@Galen I agree that Granger causality is quite limited, but most causal frameworks simply do not work for time series data and sometimes this is about the best we can do. Nevertheless, many modern research articles use some sort of modified Granger causality test to establish causality

I'm not sure what causal inference frameworks you're referring to that don't work on time series. Can you elaborate or exemplify? For example, cyclic causality (i.e. feedback loops) can be modelled in the Pearl framework by distinguishing variables by their time parameter and drawing causal arrows forward in time.
